# ¿como guardar select/option que está dentro de un foreach, en una tabla de BD, usando livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, livewire

Tengo una tabla en la BD donde almaceno preguntas, dentro de la vista hago un foreach para mostrar todas estas preguntas, estas preguntas se responden con un si o no, por eso debajo de la pregunta le agrego un select/option

```
@foreach ($preguntas as $pregunta)
        <p>{{$pregunta->titulo}}</p>
        <p>{{$pregunta->id}}</p>
        <select wire:model="respuesta" name="pregunta" id="pregunta">
            <option value="" selected></option>
            <option value="si">SI</option>
            <option value="no">NO</option>
        </select>
@endforeach
```

esto es lo que se muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que busco es guardar las respuestas de esas preguntas en una tabla de la BD, de la mejor manera, usando livewire, lo que intenté fue que en el select puse `wire:model="respuesta"` y en el componente creé la variable respuesta como un array `public $respuesta=[]` pero no me guarda

Comment: Buen día, ¿Puedes agregar el componente livewire que tienes y explicar qué es lo que no te funciona?

Answer (score 2):

no tengo datos sobre tu Modelo, pero por lo que veo, no estas marcando ninguna respuesta, le estas dando SELECTED a los campos vacíos, espero te sirva algo asi como ejemplo;

```
@foreach ($preguntas as $pregunta)
    <p>{{$pregunta->titulo}}</p>
    <p>{{$pregunta->id}}</p>
    
    <select name="pregunta" id="pregunta">
        @foreach($opciones = [' ', 'SI', 'NO'] as $opcion){
            <option value="{{ $opcion }}" {{ $pregunta->respuesta == $opcion ? "selected" : ""}} > {{ $opcion }} </option>";
        @endforeach
    </select>
@endforeach
```

El ejemplo, asume que tenes una variable "respuesta", que puede tener como valor SI o NO, y con eso hace la comparación para marcar como selected utilizando el operador ternario de PHP.

Comment: si, lo que intento realmente es guardar las respuestas de todas las preguntas usando livewire

Answer (score 1):

un ejemplo fácil que puedo dar es el siguiente:

en el componente creamos un campo que se llame: `respuestas` declarado que tendrá un arreglo

```
public $respuestas = [];
```

luego en la vista antes del foreach definiremos una variable para los indices

```
@php $indice = 0; @endphp
```

dentro del foreach, al `select` en el `wire:model` le indicamos el campo `respuestas` y su `indice` de la siguiente manera:

```
@foreach ($preguntas as $pregunta)
    <p>{{$pregunta->titulo}}</p>
    <p>{{$pregunta->id}}</p>
    <select wire:model="respuestas.{{$indice}}" name="pregunta" id="pregunta">
        <option value="" selected></option>
        <option value="si">SI</option>
        <option value="no">NO</option>
    </select>
    @php $indice++; @endphp
@endforeach
```

cabe mencionar que dentro del foreach se agrego el `$indice++` antes del cierre del foreach.

para obtener un valor de la respuesta:

```
//$respuestas[{indice}]
$respuestas[0];
$respuestas[1];
$respuestas[2];
...
```

para ver todas las respuestas en el front aplica este codigo:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($respuestas); $i++)
    Índice {{$i}} : {{$respuestas[$i]}}
    <br>
@endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

para guardar los selects en el array se le debe pasar el index del array por lo que el foreach debe ir:  `($preguntas as $index=> $pregunta)`  y en el select debe ir el  `wire:model="$respuesta.{{$index}}"` , ahora me falta guardar todo ese array en una columna de en un solo registro en la base de datos